# Vagrant + Docker + Tomcat: sharing webapps folder with container

Tags: tomcat, vagrant, docker

I'm attempting to put webapps into my dockerized, vagrant tomcat installation.

pushed my progress to github: [github demo](https://github.com/mikeblum/vagrant-docker-postgres)

I got this in my vagrantfile.proxy that points to my webapps directory:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./webapps", "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps"  
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 9200
```

I have tomcat running at 8080 -> forwarded to 9200. I can see the tomcat server started up but my webapp: [tomcat sample war](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/sample/) is 404ing.

I added this line to my tomcat Dockerfile:

```
VOLUME [ "var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/" ]
```

and this in my vagrantfile itself:

```
  config.vm.define "tomcat" do |v|
v.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
  d.build_dir = "./dockerfiles/tomcat"
  d.ports = [ "8080:8080" ]
  d.volumes = ["/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/"]
  d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "./Vagrantfile.proxy"
end
```

end

Is there something I'm missing with getting vagrant to make my ./webapps directory link to var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the URL you're using to check that the app has been deployed?

Comment: localhost:8080/mywebapp since thats where the port is proxied. i see tomcat start up in the vagrant docker-log command but no WARs are deployed.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand the config, but `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 9200` looks like you should use `localhost:9200/mywebapp` to access the tomcat instance. Although, you do say you get 404, so it seems like your forwarding is working.

Comment: ahsorry my mistake you're right, i can see localhost:9200 but /mywebapp still 404s and the catalina.out doesn't show the war being exploded. i must have messed up the volume part of this or need to forward a local directory as a shared folder between the tomcat and my local machine.